# Tracking when a UIViewcontroller is instantiated or appear

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, firebase-analytics

I'm looking for a solution to track everything a `UIViewController` gets instantiated or is displayed on screen **without** using a base view controller as a superclass.
I know `Firebase Analytics` do it for the event `screen_view`, but haven't found a similar way to do it yet.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: When do you want to do this? In the field, or just during development? Do you want to do it for every view controller, or only those of a particular type?

Comment: I'd need to have it on release, not only development.
Also yea, for every `UIViewcontroller` and it's subclasses